# Pandas: replace values in one dataframe with values from another dataframe based on two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
d1 = {'id_': ['a','b','c','d'],
     'year':['2018','2019','2017','2019']}
d2 = {'id_': ['a','c','e'],
     'year':['2015',NaN,'2012']}
test1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
test2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)


    id_ year
0   a   2018
1   b   2019
2   c   2017
3   d   2019

    id_ year
0   a   2015
1   c   None
2   e   2012
```

I need to replace `year` values in `test1` with `year` values from `test2` only when `id_` match. If the value is NaN, I'd like to keep the old value.

```
So the result looks like:

        id_ year
    0   a   2015
    1   b   2019
    2   c   2017
    3   d   2019
```

All answers I came across were based on index or mapping old values to new values using dictionaries.
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: `set_index` and `fillna`?

Comment: `test2.combine_first(test1)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang won't update test1 with test2. IanS, will add the unwanted id=e in the result.

Comment: @cs95 assuming the same index `test1.fillna(test1,inplace=True)` doesn't work?

Comment: @QuangHoang No, because that won't replace (for example) 2018 with 2015 for index a?

Comment: Ah, I read the wrong problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use `concat` and `drop_duplicates` here.

```
test3 = test2[test2['id_'].isin(test1['id_'])].dropna()
pd.concat([test1, test3]).drop_duplicates('id_', keep='last')   

  id_  year
1   b  2019
2   c  2017
3   d  2019
0   a  2015
```

---

Here's a `merge`-based alternative.

```
test3 = test1.merge(test2, on='id_', how='left')
test3['year'] = test3.pop('year_y').fillna(test3.pop('year_x'))
test3

  id_  year
0   a  2015
1   b  2019
2   c  2017
3   d  2019
```

Comment: I guess both answers work but I used concat and drop. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using `update`

```
test1=test1.set_index('id_')
test1.update(test2.set_index('id_'))
test1.reset_index(inplace=True)
test1
Out[582]: 
  id_  year
0   a  2015
1   b  2019
2   c  2017
3   d  2019
```